# Facebook group data

Tags: ruby, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I'm following this:

> ### How To Download Your Facebook Group Data
>
> Here are instructions for Mac users to download Facebook group data,
>   courtesy of Al Shaw.
>
> 1. Get an access token for your group from the Facebook Graph API Explorer. A box will pop up. Make sure you click the
>      user.groupspermission, and then click Get Access Token again. Copy and
>      paste this into a text editor.
> 2. Copy and paste your group ID (example: https://www.facebook.com/groups/209024949216061/) into a text editor.
>      You can also test your group ID in the Facebook Graph API Explorer by
>      entering “GROUPID/feed” in the get field. You should see all of your
>      group posts.
> 3. Grab the script for scraping the feed here:
>      https://gist.github.com/4322279/
> 4. Click “download gist” and decompress the file on your computer.
> 5. Navigate to where that file exists in the terminal (example: iMac:/
>      myname$ cd /Users/myname/documents). Here are instructions on how to
>      use the terminal. Stack Overflow is also a good place to go with
>      questions.
> 6. In your terminal, type: “sudo gem install crack fastercsv rest-client” and hit return. You’ll have to enter your network
>      password.
> 7. Type: “ruby fb_scrape.rb YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN YOUR_GROUP_ID” and hit return. Make sure to note that this is two pieces of information: your
>      access token, and your group id – both of which you pasted into a text
>      editor earlier.
>
> You'll see all the Facebook data fly across the
>   screen. A file should show up in your gist folder (check in your
>   Finder) called fb_posts_GROUPID.csv (with that long number being the
>   group ID you put in). Click to open, and you have your spreadsheet!

If I do it all and then issue the command I get:

```
$ ruby fb_scrape.rb CAACEdEomyaccesstokenZD 2017mygroup6335
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/crack-0.4.2/lib/crack/json.rb:33:in `rescue in parse': Invalid JSON string (Crack::ParseError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/crack-0.4.2/lib/crack/json.rb:26:in `parse'
    from fb_scrape.rb:28:in `scrape'
    from fb_scrape.rb:24:in `start'
    from fb_scrape.rb:78:in `<main>'
```

how should I fix it and why it does not work?
Thanks!

Comment: It looks to me like the scraper is expecting a JSON response, but is getting something else. I recommend [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala), which does a really good job of parsing graph API responses.

Comment: I'm not a great coder, if I need to obtain the whole group feed with likes, what should I do?

Comment: Unfortunately, this site is not about getting people to write code for you. You could try reading the documentation for the graph API and koala, and using that knowledge to modify the script you got. If you run into a specific problem while doing so (not just "how should I fix it and why it does not work"), that would be a good thing to ask about here.

Comment: The point is that I've asked about something else in the first place, but I thank you very much for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed couple of lines and it is working with Ruby 2.3.1p112

- added

  require 'json'

  require 'csv'
- changed (fastercsv -> csv & Crack::JSON.parse -> JSON.parse()

  resp = JSON.parse(RestClient.get(url))

  CSV.open("fb_posts_#{@group_id}.csv", "w") do |csv|

Comment: Is the solution still working for you?